# What are the color names in TERM=xterm256 for colors > 16?

Tags: xterm

I'm trying to set my xterm background color to "color 234" in xterm256 color mode, but I don't know what to pass to the "-bg" option.  I've tried "color234", "Color234", but those are not defined.

Answer (score 7):

The `bg` option sets the X window background and has nothing to do with the emulation or the 256-color escape codes interpreted by the terminal.

You can find more about the escape codes that the terminal interprets at http://rtfm.etla.org/xterm/ctlseq.html .

According to the documentation, the escape sequence is:

- ESC[48;5;***xxx***m  (To set the background)
- ESC[38;5;***xxx***m  (To set the foreground)

Where ***xxx*** is the color value as follows:

- 0-15 are the standard ANSI colors
- 16-231 are a 6x6x6 RGB color cube given by ((36 * r) + (6 * g) + b + 16) with r,g,b in [0..5]
- 232-255 are a greyscale ramp without black and white.

The other commenter was correct about setting the background color of the window to 0x1C1C1C with `xterm -bg rgb:1c/1c/1c`, as Color #234 in the 256-color Xterm emulation is a dark grey of 0x1C1C1C as computed by http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1349: [alt text http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/img/256colors2.png](http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/img/256colors2.png)

Comment: I think you got the 38 and 48 backwards?

Comment: dangit. And I thought I double checked.

Answer (score 1):

xterm -bg rgb:1c/1c/1c is how you'd set the color using RGB values.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a chart of X11 color names.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names)

You may have `/etc/X11/rgb.txt` on your system.